# Eclipse: turn off highlighting of every iteration of a word when I select that word?

Tags: eclipse, select, highlight

It has been a long time since I created a new Eclipse workspace.  I long ago forgot the preferences I set and became with.

I notice now, in my new workspace, that every time I select a word, every iteration of that word also gets highlighted.

How can I turn this off?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use : 
`Windows->Preferences->Java->Editor->Mark Occurrences->Mark 
occurrences of the selected element in the current file`

Or : `alt+shift+o`